# Means of determining monotonicity of missing pattern other than eyeballing? And how monotone is monotone for the purpose of multiple imputation?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I have a large dataset with a large number of variables. Missingness as high as ~25% in some variables, many vars with no missing.

Judgment of the monotonicity of the missing pattern is important for the selection of a multiple imputation method. I have seen some sources talk about "monotone or near-monotone" patterns. But how monotone is monotone, and how do you know, other than by looking?

Every text I have seen recommends eyeballing the patterns. But is there not some means of statistically summarizing monotonicity (e.g., sum of belongingness the main missing pattern controlling for belongingness to other patterns)?

I have not seen anything like this in any text, but maybe I'm just missing it.

If I organize the data matrix to maximize the number of missing measurements clustered in a monotone pattern, I have about 35% of measurements in the pattern. (Other measurements display something of a "fan" pattern similar to that seen [here](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/SPSS_SC/Module6/EM_Miss_006.PNG). How would I decide whether this were monotonic "enough" to assume it for the purpose of MI?

I know that I could also do MI in two steps in order to isolated the monotonic pattern, then run MI again with a monotone method. As fun as this sounds, I'm trying to determine whether it's reasonable to do it in one fell swoop.

Comment: On why fell swoop, see http://www.dailywritingtips.com/one-fell-swoop/

Answer (score 3):

Rico, with today's chained equations algorithms, you typically do not need to worry about monotonicity, though exploiting it may make convergence more rapid and stable.

Section 4.1 of my book *Flexible Imputation of Missing Data* proposes two new measures to summarize the missing data pattern: influx and outflux. This pair can be used to diagnose monotonicity quickly.